# how to self join a table in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in sql server 2008 with format:

```
Name                                   number
a                                       123
a                                       231
b                                       521
b                                       236
```

then i want get result :

```
Name                                    number
a                                        123,231
b                                        521,236
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using concatenate in xml path.

```
        Create table #t ( Name varchar(1),Number int)
        Insert into #t
        values
        ('a',123),
        ('a',231),
        ('b',521),
        ('b',236)


        Select distinct
        t.name,
        stuff(
            ( Select ','+ convert(varchar(50),number)
            from #t t1
             where t.name =t1.name
             order by name
             for xml path ('')
             )
             ,1,2,'') as number


        from #t t
        order by name
```

Comment: Either the third argument of STUFF should be 1 instead of 2 or the delimiter should be something like `', '` i.e. 2 characters instead of 1.